# jquery ui autocomplete combobox widget example modified for ajax source

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3

Has anyone successfully modified the above mentioned widget for ajax source? I've been able to make the modifications and it works fine with the exception of the search term highlighting of the options. More specifically the below code.

```
var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                        response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                            var text = $( this ).text();
                            if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                return {
                                    label: text.replace(
                                        new RegExp(
                                            "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                            $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                            ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                        ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }) );
```

Here's my modification to the widget:

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.Clients", {
        _create: function () {
            var self = this,
                select = this.element.hide(),
                selected = select.children(":selected"),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
            var input = this.input = $("<input>")
                .insertAfter(select)
                .val(value)
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Controller/Action", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                            data: { searchText: request.term },
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        value: item.ClientName,
                                        id: item.ClientId
                                    }
                                }))
                            }
                        })
                    },
```

Can anyone assist with integrating that functionality into my ajax call?

Comment: Any luck on resolving this issue?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The widget expects there to be a label property in the return value from the response.  The label property is what is displayed in the autocomplete window.  If you don't specify a label property, it will just the value property.  So, all you need to do is alter the original value for the label property and replace the text with item.ClientName

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.Clients", {
        _create: function () {
            var self = this,
                select = this.element.hide(),
                selected = select.children(":selected"),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
            var input = this.input = $("<input>")
                .insertAfter(select)
                .val(value)
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Controller/Action", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                            data: { searchText: request.term },
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        value: item.ClientName,
                                        id: item.ClientId,
                                        label: item.ClientName.replace(
                                                new RegExp(
                                                    "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                                    $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                                    ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                                ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                    }
                                }))
                            }
                        })
                    },
```

Comment: the code you gave above doesn't work fully for me - I see remote list of values, but I can not choose any - looks like `select` event should be also modified. Have you done it?

Comment: You shouldn't have to override the select method.  It should just be using the default select from the framework.  You see the values loaded into the element and the autocomplete works but you can't select anything?

Comment: Right. Please see my question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011323/how-to-use-remote-source-with-jquery-ui-combobox

Answer (score 0):

The demo has a nice mix of options - [Remote JSONP Datasource](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) being one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this does not pertain to my specific need.