# How to use remote source with jquery ui combobox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

There is [combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) with autocomplete enabled. How to pass JSON data as source for this combobox?

**Upd.** I've found partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804869/jquery-ui-autocomplete-combobox-widget-example-modified-for-ajax-source) - it allows me to use remote data source (original `var input = this.input = $( "<input>" ).autocomplete({ source` is replaced with remote source). But I can not choose the value - looks like the problem is with the following code (it allows to choose values from the select options (which I don't have).

```
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.item.option.selected = true;
    self._trigger( "selected", event, {
      item: ui.item.option
    });
  },
```

How to fix that?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/TFerw/2/) is the demo.

Comment: Can you add the json data ? is it remote ?

Comment: Then my answer below gives you a good example

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working example - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/TFerw/3/

Remote end should return some values (most popular) in case when empty `term` is requested - it happens when user presses combobox button.

Comment: Btw, it doesn't work fully properly - value of the combobox always equal to the initial value.

Comment: Yes, but it's trivial to fix:

    input.autocomplete("search", input.value);

Have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/SjcP5/1/

Comment: @SeanCameron I have updated your fiddle and fixed a small bug. Take a look at: [jsfiddle.net/gzuri/4wutG/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/gzuri/4wutG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Example taken from the link you added in your question :

```
        $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
            source: "search.php", // remote site
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have combobox, not standard autocomplete. I've tried to call `$( "#cbCity" ).combobox();` and then `$( "#cbCity" ).autocomplete(...` with your code - it doesn't work.

Comment: @LA_ Can you add your javascript code to your question or use http://jsfiddle.net/ then I will take another look

Answer (score 0):

I just used next construction:
1. In combobox.js I put code from example that appears on https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox and had changed *_create* & *_createAutocomplete* functions as follows:

```
 _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
            .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
            .insertAfter( this.element );

        var autocompleteSetup = this.options.autocompleteSetup;
        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete( autocompleteSetup );
        this._createShowAllButton();
    }

    _createAutocomplete: function(setupObject) {
...
this.input = $( "<input>" )
            .appendTo( this.wrapper )
            .val( value )
            .attr( "title", "" )
            .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
            .autocomplete(setupObject)...
```

2. From page code where I'm creating the combo I am calling the create code as follows:

   var options = {
       autocompleteSetup : {
           delay: 100,
           minLength: 2,
           source: "http://your/data/hook/url"
       }
   };
   $( "#subzero" ).combobox(options);