# Jquery UI: combobox with remote autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, combobox

I use jQuery UI with it's autocomplete plugin. I want to have a jQueryUi-like combobox (with an arrow on which one can click to see a list), but when someone enters some text in the combobox/textfield, the data is retrieved from backend. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Where's your question? any examples of your code that aren't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/TFerw/3/

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011323/how-to-use-remote-source-with-jquery-ui-combobox)

Comment: This is not a solution: that field is not like a combobox (has no down-arrow to click on) which means, he can not display some default data.

Comment: I edited the answer based on the fact you also want a combobox

Comment: Yes, but it won't be with autocomplete ... the request is made only one time... and then, I would like to use jQuery UI, the autocomplete feature

Comment: I will be autocomplete since you set the datasource as described in http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: I suppose the ul element should be a combobox and the li elements are options? And after building the combobox so, I should attach the autocomplete?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.