# how to trigger search in jquery autocomplete combobox?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, combobox, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jquery combobox and relying on the source code provided there. I need data provided from a remote source, so I hooked it up with ajax. However, since AJAX is an asynchronous call, I need to update the combobox with the search result data.

> How can I trigger a search on the combobox ?

Snippet:

```
/* In 
$.widget( "ui.combobox", {
            _create: function() {
// input definition
*/
.autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        // implements retrieving and filtering data from the select
        var term = request.term;

        if(term.length >= 2){
            var abbreviation = term.substring(0,2);
            if(!(abbreviation in cache)){
                searchResultData = searchCities(abbreviation);
                updateOptions(select, searchResultData);
                cache[abbreviation] = 1;
            }
        }

        // updates the search widget with options matching request.term
        var responseData = filterOptionsForResponse(select, term);

        response(responseData);
    },
```

Rest of the code is as is provided on the jquery site.
Above code works absolutely fine when `searchCities(abbreviation)` returns local array of objects.

- `searchCities(abbreviation)` : returns an array of cities matching abbreviation
- `updateOptions(select, data)`: Update the options in the select combobox with the given data
- `filterOptionsForResponse(select, term)`: updates the combobx with options matching term based on Regex

My current version of searchCities with ajax:

```
function searchCities(abbreviation){
    if(!!abbreviation){
        $.ajax({
                url: "/wah/destinationsJson.action",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: abbreviation
                },
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data){
                    updateOptions($("#searchbox"), data.cities);
                    // $("#searchbox input").trigger('autocompleteselect', data.term);
                    // return data.cities;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

The above trigger does not trigger a search! Can someone please explain me how can I trigger a search on this combobox.

PS: I'm sorry for not providing a jsfiddle/jsbin, since I could not get it to render there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work!

http://jsfiddle.net/SRekL/

Lines of interest:

> input -> source -> ajax -> success

```
success: function(data) {
    optionData = $.map(data.geonames,function(item){
        return new Object( {name: item.adminName1} ); ;
    });

    updateOptions(select, optionData);
    response(filterOptionsForResponse(select, term));
    return;
}
```

**Notes:**

- Transforming optionData into an array of objects, since my function `updateOptions(...)` rely on a property "name".
- `updateOptions(select, optionData)`: Updates the options of this combobox with the returned data
- `filterOptionsForResponse(select, term)`: Filters the options based on term and highlights the matched text.

This solution is tailored for my requirement where I need to hit the server with the first two characters. I filter the options based on the searched term and also append the result set into the given list of options.

To demo, I used "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON" as the URL for ajax call in the jsFiddle.

Also, a chain of threads on SO proved to me of great help:

- [Under the hood of jquery combobox](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/a-jquery-ui-combobox-under-the-hood) - Single most valuable article which explains the inners of combobox

`Clue trail`

- [How to use remote source with jquery ui combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011323/how-to-use-remote-source-with-jquery-ui-combobox)
- [jquery ui autocomplete combobox widget example modified for ajax source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804869/jquery-ui-autocomplete-combobox-widget-example-modified-for-ajax-source)
- http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/TFerw/3/